# How might I set my browser to only download files/links from whichever domain I'm browsing?

Tags: webbrowser-control, same-origin-policy, pagespeed

If I browse to example.com, I want to block any links to ads, third-party APIs, fonts, CDMs, etc. that might need to be downloaded from other sites.  I want a quasi "same origin policy," giving me ONLY the bare bones of that web page.  I realize this will make some (most?) sites look funky, but I don't care about aesthetics, I want speed and simplicity and no fluff.